# Is there a way to add realtime gps navigation onto a web app

Tags: reactjs, web, navigation, gps

Hi I am writing a react webapp(if needed can Switch to something else)

Is there a way to add realtime gps navigation onto my app

Example:
Write a place into a input field after that give you directions to that place while you are going (like Google Maps) Is any way to do this?

EDIT: I am just gonna have a list of places and guiding on turns etc. using the gps signal

Comment: I voted to close this question because there are usually hundreds of ways to implement a feature; too many to enumerate here. Furthermore, a full answer to any one of them could require many pages or even a full book. Rather than asking for an approach, [edit] your question to focus on a more specific problem you encounter when you actually try to implement it yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the perfect question and how to create a [Minimal , Complete and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)